# TeXstudio default setting saves the .pdf and auxiliary files to a different location than the .tex file on a MacBook M2 Pro

Tags: texstudio, installing, mactex, macos

I have recently transitioned from a Windows machine to Apple silicon. I have a MacBook M2 Pro.

I just installed TeXstudio on my MacBook. So, I was trying to create a document to see how it works out on a Mac. I saved my .tex file in the document folder given in the Finder, which is the default file manager. However, after compiling the .tex file, I found that the respective .pdf and auxiliary files got saved in the following location:
"/private/var/folders/41/cm7sh_pd0491hkz5cww1pcg80000gn/T".

I don't know how to change the default settings of TeXstudio so that those files get saved to the same location as the .tex file. I didn't face this issue on the Windows machine, so I never learned how to change the default settings of TeXstudio. I googled a lot for the solution before posting here but couldn't go anywhere.

Can somebody help me fix this problem?